# What does = () => mean in react components

Tags: javascript

What does `= () =>` mean in the below code

```
enterclass Counter extends React.Component {
  tick = () => {
    ...
  }
  ...
} code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, it's assigning a function to the `tick` variable. The `() => { ... }` is the function. It's an ES6-style "arrow" function expression. These are like `function` expressions (`tick = function() { ... }`) except that the `this` value within the function is inherited from the context in which it's defined rather than being set when the function is called.

Here's a simple example of the difference (requires an ES6-enabled JavaScript engine):

```
var obj = {
  method: function() {
    var a = ['x'];
    snippet.log("this === obj? " + (this === obj));
    a.forEach(function() { // Non-arrow function
      snippet.log("nonarrow this === obj? " + (this === obj));
    });
    a.forEach(() => {      // Arrow function
      snippet.log("arrow this === obj? " + (this === obj));
    });
  }
};
obj.method(); // this == obj? true
              // nonarrow this === obj? false
              // arrow this === obj? true
```

[**Live Copy**](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20method%3A%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20a%20%3D%20%5B'x'%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj%3F%20%22%20%2B%20(this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a.forEach(function()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20Non-arrow%20function%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22nonarrow%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj%3F%20%22%20%2B%20(this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a.forEach(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Arrow%20function%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22arrow%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj%3F%20%22%20%2B%20(this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Aobj.method()%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20%3D%3D%20obj%3F%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20nonarrow%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj%3F%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20arrow%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20obj%3F%20true) on Babel's REPL

Note how the arrow function's `this` is the same as `this` in the context where it was created, but the non-arrow function's `this` isn't (instead, it's set by how `forEach` calls it).

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature from ES6 called "arrow function": https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#arrows

It's basically a shorthand for:

```
var tick = function () { ... }.bind(this);
```